# Equation of motion of scalar field

Tags: general-relativity, ads-cft

I have the metric of the five dimensional Schwarzschild AdS space with metric $$ds^2=-\frac{L^2}{z^2}(1-\frac{z^4}{z_H^4})dt^2+\frac{L^2}{z^2}\frac{1}{(1-\frac{z^4}{z_H^4})}dz^2+\frac{L^2}{z^2}(dx_1^2+dx_2^2+dx_3^2),$$ where $z_H$ is the horizon and the equation of motion for a scalar field in this background is written as $$\frac{z_H^8{\omega}^2}{(z^4-z_H^4)^2}\phi(z)+\frac{z^4+3z_H^4}{z^5-zz_H^4}\phi'(z)+\phi''(z)=0$$, where $\omega$ is the frequency and $z_H$ I related to the temperature of th black hole as $z_H=1/\pi T$. I want to study this equation in the limit $\omega z_H\gg 1$, so I make a change of variables $\hat{\omega}=\omega z_H$ and $\hat{z}=z/z_H$. The equation reduces to $$\frac{\hat{\omega}^2\phi(\hat{z})}{(-1+\hat{z}^4)^2}+\frac{(3+\hat{z}^4)\phi'(\hat{z})}{\hat{z}(-1+\hat{z}^4)}+\phi''(\hat{z})=0.$$ From this equation, how do I study the case $\hat{\omega}\gg 1$?

Comment: Work in terms of dimensionless quantities. Define $x \equiv z/z_H$ and $a = \omega z_H$. Write out the equation in terms of $x$ and $a$. Then take the limit $a \to \infty$ and see of that helps.